# GWT / Eclipse slow : just unusable (win7 / Juno install)

Tags: eclipse, performance, gwt

I have Eclipse Juno + latest GWT (GPE 3.1.2+ SDK 2.5.1).
It's just unusable :

1. Just hang-up now and then (ten times a day), so I have to kill and restart
2. At best very slow, meaning waiting minutes before UI response for trivial things

After WEB investigation, i did :

1. increased JVM resources in eclipse.ini
2. periodically purge the project folder "gwt-unitCache"

For some reason i also tried GWT on Indigo (as the GWT Designer does not run properly on Juno), but it is the same.
The issues seem to be yet somewhere else.
As there as performance issues posted on Google bug list, I am not too sure where I stand.

So my questions :

1. Does anyone use Eclipse/GWT with fair performances [on Windows ?
   (is the issue related to windows -- which I doubt)]
2. Can anyone provide a set of configuration instructions which can
   lead to a stable config ? -- or explain the traps to avoid ?

Before going to Vaadin I wanted to properly handle GWT, but i am close to drop it. Please help.

Comment: Check your temp folder and do some cleanup if necessary: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5261 Juno is also known to be slower than Indigo.

Comment: Can you mention your hardware - ram,diskspace,cpu and os details?

Comment: "Does anyone use Eclipse/GWT with fair performance" Yes, and I have seen it running smoothly on all OS. That said, on a system that ran Windows 7 with *1 GB* of RAM, I have seen performance issues quite similar to the ones you describe.

Comment: @SSR  My HW config : RAM 4Gbytes; Intel i5 2 CPUs 2.27Ghz; diskspace : hundreds of Gb free. I checked perfmon, but when eclipse get stuck there is no clues that it is because of overload.  I have the feeling the java editor is poor. I tend to edit in notepad++, then go back to eclipse to refresh file and run as ...  Is the GWT java editor the native one from eclipse ?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer : I saw this bug.  I am not sure which "temp folder" to look at. C:\tmp is empty. I have no temp folder in my user home.

Comment: No user-specific temp folder?! Double check, it's hidden by default: `C:`Users\Gerard\AppData\Local\Temp` (`Gerard` being your username)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer : Yes indeed ! There, I had 7GB... I'll see if things will go better. Tx.

Comment: My intuition up to know : this Eclipse/GWT pair suffers from massive memory leaks. For instance sometimes I get errors about a PemGen space. To prevent too many crashes, I use to edit separately in notepad++.  Thanks to that, there are good times when it crashes less often = every 30 minutes.  Given also the lack of clear status/resolution about this kind of problem which shows here and there on the Web, my conclusion is that Eclipse/GWT is not an environment for professional dev. Too much loss of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would add RAM.  4 gigs sounds pretty slim for a dev machine.  An OS with a few apps running will take up 2 gigs.  Start eclipse and that's another gig or 2 easy.  Then you start running jetty within eclipse for another gig or 2 and now you're hitting your virtual memory / page file which will slow it down tremendously.

Running firefox doing nothing else then looking at a single tab to test my app is 200MB of RAM.  Some of my chrome tabs are 100MB easy.  Just figure each browser tab eats 3-5% of your 4 gigs.

I'd say get at least 16GB on a 64bit OS and give eclipse and jetty at least 2 gigs each if not 4 each.  A solid state disk (SSD) helps a lot too since compiling does a lot of random reads and writes.

Here's a screenshot of the debug settings with 3 gigs of RAM and some extra permgen space for subsequent refreshes of the pages.  Just remember, if you run out of physical RAM and it starts hitting the page file these settings won't increase performance!
[image: Eclipse GWT Debug Settings for more ram and permgen space]